# Reading values from BLE device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I'm owning a Polar H10 chest strap which operates with blueooth low energy and provides heart rate and heart rate variability.

I want to read out these values with an Android app. I'm able to connect to the device thanks to the help in the [official BLE tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html#close). The problem now is to read out the heart rate and heart rate variability values from the device. Everytime a new value is available on the device I want to read out this value (and there are at least every second new values).

I have found the following pieces of code:

```
private static double extractHeartRate(
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {

        int flag = characteristic.getProperties();
        Log.d(TAG, "Heart rate flag: " + flag);
        int format = -1;
        // Heart rate bit number format
        if ((flag & 0x01) != 0) {
            format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16;
            Log.d(TAG, "Heart rate format UINT16.");
        } else {
            format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8;
            Log.d(TAG, "Heart rate format UINT8.");
        }
        final int heartRate = characteristic.getIntValue(format, 1);
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("Received heart rate: %d", heartRate));
        return heartRate;
    }



private static Integer[] extractBeatToBeatInterval(
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {

        int flag = characteristic.getIntValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8, 0);
        int format = -1;
        int energy = -1;
        int offset = 1; // This depends on hear rate value format and if there is energy data
        int rr_count = 0;

        if ((flag & 0x01) != 0) {
            format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16;
            Log.d(TAG, "Heart rate format UINT16.");
            offset = 3;
        } else {
            format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8;
            Log.d(TAG, "Heart rate format UINT8.");
            offset = 2;
        }
        if ((flag & 0x08) != 0) {
            // calories present
            energy = characteristic.getIntValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16, offset);
            offset += 2;
            Log.d(TAG, "Received energy: {}"+ energy);
        }
        if ((flag & 0x16) != 0){
            // RR stuff.
            Log.d(TAG, "RR stuff found at offset: "+ offset);
            Log.d(TAG, "RR length: "+ (characteristic.getValue()).length);
            rr_count = ((characteristic.getValue()).length - offset) / 2;
            Log.d(TAG, "RR length: "+ (characteristic.getValue()).length);
            Log.d(TAG, "rr_count: "+ rr_count);
            if (rr_count > 0) {
                Integer[] mRr_values = new Integer[rr_count];
                for (int i = 0; i < rr_count; i++) {
                    mRr_values[i] = characteristic.getIntValue(
                            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16, offset);
                    offset += 2;
                    Log.d(TAG, "Received RR: " + mRr_values[i]);
                }
                return mRr_values;
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "No RR data on this update: ");
        return null;
    }
```

How can I use it to extract the heart rate and r-r intervals (beat to beat intervals) assuming that I have a connection to the device? I would be happy if somebody could make a short example. Addtionally, I would like to use a service so that it runs in the background and I can do other work and it drains less battery. But the service should have highest priority so that it get not killed.

In the `extractBeatToBeatInterval()` method there is a `int offset = 1;` with the description

> This depends on hear rate value format and if there is energy data

I don't understand the meaning of this offest. What offset value should I use?

Second, if the connection breaks I would like to get a notification so that I can handle it (e.g. displaying a message). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can help you with a few things on this matter.
For connection breaks you can handle it like this

```
public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            if (newState == BluetoothGatt.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                Log.e(Constants.TAGGattConnectThread, "Connected to the GATT Server " + status + " " +newState);
                Log.e(Constants.TAGGattConnectThread, "Attempting to discover services");
                bluetoothGatt.discoverServices();
            }
            else if(newState == BluetoothGatt.STATE_DISCONNECTED)
            {
                Log.e(Constants.TAGGattConnectThread,"Band disconnected");
               //Write you disconnect handling code here
            }
```

Also you can set the 'AutoConnect option to 'True' while connecting to Gatt

```
bluetoothGatt = bluetoothDevice.connectGatt(context, true, bluetoothGattCallback);
```

---

For creating a service, You can create a Sticky service that will restart itself unless force stopped.